SVM Kernel to compare histograms as input vectors
In lecture 7 of CS229 by Andrew Ng he mentions at the very end a specific Kernel that allows an SVM to "classify" how similar two histograms are, such as the demographics of 2 countries. He describes that "the kernel takes the min of both histograms and sums them up".
Here is the lecture video at the timestamp where he mentions this: youtube link
Does someone know which kernel he means or have any resources to this topic? Thanks in advance!

That's the Histogram Intersection Kernel. Let's say you have two histograms from images $A$ and $B$, and $a_i$ and $b_i$ represent the i-th bin in each histogram, with total m bins. The kernel $K_{int}$ function measures the similarity between the two histograms.
$$
K_{int}(A, B)=\sum_{i=1}^{m} \min\{{a_i}, {b_i}\}
$$
Assuming $A$ and $B$ have the same image size, let $N$ be the total number of pixels. Both $A$ and $B$ are binary vectors of size $N \times m$:
$$
A=(\underbrace{1, 1, ..., 1}_{a_1}, \underbrace{0, 0, ..., 0}_{N-a_
1},\\ \underbrace{1, 1, ..., 1}_{a_2}, \underbrace{0, 0, ..., 0}_{N-a_2},\\ ..., \underbrace{1, 1, ..., 1}_{a_m}, \underbrace{0, 0, ..., 0}_{N-a_m})
$$
Because the $\min$ operation pick the smallar one for each bin, and A and B are only binary vectors. $K_{int}(A, B)$ can be seen as the inner product $A\cdot B$
If you want to use the Histogram Intersection Kernel for populations in two countries, you will need to normalize the histogram areas.
Original paper: HISTOGRAM INTERSECTION KERNEL
FOR IMAGE CLASSIFICATION
